# Vapor SQLite missing module CSQLiteMac

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm trying to add SQLite to a Vapor app but not having much luck. Here is what I have done to add it to the project and the error I get in Xcode when I try an build it. The error is in Sqlite.swift on the import statement:  "No such module 'CSQLiteMac'"  I know there is a missing framework somewhere but I just can't seem to track down what I'm missing and my google fu is failing me.

```
myke$ brew update
Already up-to-date.

myke$ brew install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
Error: No available formula with the name "libsqlite3-dev"
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
==> You haven't updated Homebrew in a while.
A formula for libsqlite3-dev might have been added recently.
Run `brew update` to get the latest Homebrew updates!

myke$ vapor build --clean
Cleaning [Done]
No Packages folder, fetch may take a while...
Fetching Dependencies [Done]
Building Project [Done]

myke$ vapor xcode
Fetching Dependencies [Done]
Generating Xcode Project [Done]
Select the `App` scheme to run.
Open Xcode project?
y/n>n
```

My Package file:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "kanban",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 0),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/sqlite-provider.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 0)
    ],
    exclude: [
        "Config",
        "Database",
        "Localization",
        "Public",
        "Resources",
        "Tests",
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
brew install sqlite3
```

The `sqlite3` package is never getting installed because it's failing on

```
Error: No available formula with the name "libsqlite3-dev"
```

Comment: So that was half of my problem. Once I got sqlite installed I was still getting the error. I had to add:

"$(SRCROOT)/Packages/CSQLite-1.0.0"

to the Search Paths for the SQLite target.